# Fire a method after transclude has finished

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular directive that creates an accordion out of `<ol>` and `<li>` elements, with each `<li>`'s content being wrapped in a transcluded template. I need to fire a method to check if any of these `<li>` elements has an error, and open that accordion, but I can't find a way to fire the method *after* the elements have been transcluded.

Is there a hook or directive config that will time this correctly?

Comment: Something like this would be helpful for me too. I guess you can broadcast or emit an event in AngularJS. But it also depends on how you transclude your content. The way ng-if does it is different from ng-repeat, and also depends on if you're transclude is set to true or "element".

Comment: @b.e.hollenbeck could you add plunkr/fiddle of the same?

Comment: We would need to see how your directive is structured and some sample html to see how it works.  Then we can see what can be done. The docs mention a callback that you can use: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion-functions

Comment: its very similar to how angular handles form validations.. you have parent directive to while all child directive informs about their state and then parent/child can do furuther processing based on current state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can access content in `postLink` function defined in directive definition object. Check official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Directive definition object enables you to define:

```
compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
  return {
    pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
  }
  // or
  // return function postLink( ... ) { ... }
},
```

and there you can inject and access iElement and its content. This happens after template compilation so `<li>` elements should be already in place.

Comment: If he's going to use post link, might as well just use ``link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl)`` instead of compile.